# How does $this->db->trans_status() work in codeigniter transactions?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions

How exactly does `$this->db->trans_status()` in CodeIgniter understand that whether the queries in the transaction were successful or not?

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Am using **MySQL** as the underlying database

Comment: Why not take a look through [CI's source code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter) and see for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a statement for `START TRANSACTION` one `COMMIT` and one for `ROLLBACK`.

Your database driver and/or abstraction layer doesn't *have* to send the entire list at once:

```
$query_string = '
    START TRANSACTION;
        SELECT something FROM somewhere;
        UPDATE something SET something.we_have = something.else;
    COMMIT;';
$dba->execute($query_string);
```

They can be sent individually and the driver and/or abstraction layer can wait for the query to execute and return an SQL STATUS.

```
$query_string = 'START TRANSACTION;';
$dba->execute($query_string);

$query_string = 'SELECT something FROM somewhere;';
$dba->execute($query_string);

$query_string = 'UPDATE something SET something.we_have = something.else;';
$dba->execute($query_string);
$status = $dba->get_status();

if($status)
    $query_string = 'COMMIT;';
else // darn our update must have failed
    $dba->execute($query_string);
```

And based on that status you can decide weather to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Of course this implies that the overall time spent by your script in connecting to the DB is bigger than if it would've just shoved the entire string down the pipe in one connection.

Comment: thanks @Mihai. I am interested to know how does dba->get_status() understand that it, in fact, is returning the correct status of the SQL? Is it based on SQL deadlock issues? Is it based on malformed SQL strings? Is it based on timeout issues? I actually have about 10 to 15 SQLs between a trans_start and trans_complete.

Comment: Either you've only encountered SQL STATEs that had clear messages attached by the DB engine or the DBA inspects stiff like SHOW INNODB STATUS to look for state info.

Comment: I've checked [the code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php) of CI_DB_Driver it just checks if there are any errors in the previous query. It doesn't seam to be implemented lower down in MySQL's concrete driver class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mess:

```
if($status)
    $query_string = 'COMMIT;';
else // darn our update must have failed
    $dba->execute($query_string);
```

Maybe you want:

```
if($status)
    $query_string = 'COMMIT';
else // darn our update must have failed
    $query_string = 'ROLLBACK';

$dba->execute($query_string);
```